# scala treeset ordering causes elements to disappear?

Tags: scala

Can someone help me understand the following, please? If I create a treemap of elements, scala seems to decide that my compare method also determines the equality of the elements, and therefore removes elements that are the same according to the 'compare' method. I'm not expecting this, since equality should still be defined according to object equality if I haven't overridden it?

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

class A(val num: Int) extends Ordered[A] {
    def compare (that: A) = {
        this.num - that.num
    }
    override def toString() = {
      num+""
    }
}

object A {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {

        val mySet = new TreeSet[A]()
        mySet += new A(3)
        mySet += new A(2)
        mySet += new A(1)
        mySet += new A(3)
        mySet += new A(2)
        mySet += new A(1)

        mySet.foreach(println)
    }
}
```

gives

```
1
2
3
```

not the expected (by me)

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuitive assumption is understandable, **but in general `TreeSet` implementations often rely on comparison methods rather than equality, since the `compare` operations returns `0`  only if the two objects are equal**; for Scala, it says so in the [doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.0/index.html#scala.math.Ordered) (`compare` method).

In Java's `TreeSet` this is even [mentioned explicitly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

In Scala, this is not as obvious from the docs, but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/TreeSet.scala#L1),  you'll see that the Scala `TreeSet` relies on the `RedBlackTree` implementation internally, which, [in its `lookup` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/RedBlackTree.scala), uses the result of `compare` for testing equality exclusively.

And that's perfectly valid, due to `Ordering.compare`'s contract, as noted in the first paragraph - i.e. if you get `0`, the two objects are equal by definition.

Comment: Wow, thank you for a very full and very fast answer! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

from the doc:

" It is important that the equals method for an instance of Ordered[A] be consistent with the compare method. However, due to limitations inherent in the type erasure semantics, there is no reasonable way to provide a default implementation of equality for instances of Ordered[A]"

So you should be providing your own hashcode and equals methods by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, SortedSet doesn't allow duplicates, so in your code, the tree last insertions are ignored