# Any way to prevent Scala TreeSet replacing equivalent values

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Using Scala 2.10.2 - I want to build a sorted set of floating point values with comparison based on a specified tolerance, as per this example:

```
implicit object DiffAtLeastOne extends Ordering[Double] {
  def compare(a: Double, b: Double): Int =
    if ((a - b).abs < 1.0) 0
    else a.compare(b)
}


val ts = scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet.empty[Double]
ts += 0.0
ts += 0.9
ts += 1.8
println( ts )  // prints TreeSet(1.8)
```

I had expected that because successive values are seen as equivalent, the set would retain the first (0.0) and the last (1.8) but instead it replaces each previous value with the next. Is there a simple way of preventing this without sub-classing TreeSet (which gives a deprecation warning) ?

Apologies if this is a duplicate - I trawled for a while without success.

**UPDATE:**

After looking at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19862237/40246) and @user2864740's comment I realized that I need to make the equals method of my values type conform to the Ordering.compare method. The following is ugly but gives the behaviour that I'm after:

```
case class RoundedDouble(value: Double) {
  import RoundedDouble._

  override def equals(other: Any): Boolean =
    if (other.isInstanceOf[RoundedDouble]) {
      val otherRD = other.asInstanceOf[RoundedDouble]
      DiffAtLeastOne.compare(this, otherRD) == 0
    }
    else false
}

object RoundedDouble {
  implicit object DiffAtLeastOne extends Ordering[RoundedDouble] {
    def compare(a: RoundedDouble, b: RoundedDouble): Int =
      if ((a.value - b.value).abs < 1.0) 0
      else a.value.compare(b.value)
  }  

  implicit def fromDouble(d: Double) = RoundedDouble(d)
}


val ts = scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet.empty[RoundedDouble]
ts += 0.0
ts += 0.9
ts += 1.8

println( ts )  // prints TreeSet(RoundedDouble(0.0), RoundedDouble(1.8))
```

No doubt there is a much more elegant alternative.

Comment: The code performs the task exactly as prescribed. The Set has no care (or really way of knowing) about the difference in the *first* and *last* values used, only the *existing* and the *being-added* values: 1.8 replaces 0.9 which itself replaced 0.0 - Maybe a Set is not appropriate?

Comment: @user2864740 I was under the (possibly mistaken) impression that TreeSet used the compare method of its Ordering when testing if a value is already contained. Is that not the case ?

Comment: Insert 0 -> Set: {0} ; Insert 0.9 -> Set: {0.9} ; Insert 1.8 -> Set {1.8}. Every insert *only* cares about the *existing* and the *being-added* values. The problem in this case is that *each value added replaces the previous value* (because it is within "tolerance" of the *previous* value). A subclass would not fix this. Compare if *only* 0 and 1.8 were inserted. Or if 0, 0.9, and 2.8 were added.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (but still hoping for better answers)...

The following composition solution (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14684608/40246)) seems to do what I need:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{SortedSet, TreeSet}

object RoundedDoubleSortedSet {
  val Tolerance = 1.0e-8

  def almostEq(a: Double, b: Double) =
    (a - b).abs < Tolerance

  val ordering = new Ordering[Double] {
    def compare(a: Double, b: Double): Int =
      if (almostEq(a, b)) 0
      else a.compare(b)
  }
}

final class RoundedDoubleSortedSet extends SortedSet[Double] {

  override val ordering: Ordering[Double] = RoundedDoubleSortedSet.ordering 
  private val ts = TreeSet.empty[Double](ordering)

  override def contains(x: Double) = ts.contains(x)
  override def += (x: Double) = { if (!contains(x)) ts += x; this }
  override def -= (x: Double) = { ts -= x; this }  
  override def iterator: Iterator[Double] = ts.iterator
  override def keysIteratorFrom(start: Double): Iterator[Double] = ts.keysIteratorFrom(start)
  override def rangeImpl(from: Option[Double], until: Option[Double]) = ts.rangeImpl(from, until)
}
```